# Compare each records of same table in sql server and return duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table like below.I wanted to get the duplicate records.Here the condition if date2 and date4 having same date OR dates within less than or equals to 10 days of each other then records are duplicate. I have around 2000 records in the DB.Showing here few sample example.
Date1 can be ignored. It may be same date or may be different.

```
ID Number   Code Type   date1     Date2       date3        Date4     status   shortname     CP      deferred
1  EO2      C    TO   9/20/2000  9/1/2010   9/18/2010   9/1/2010     Archi    Ordinary  58.65586    0
2  EO2      C    TO   9/20/2000  9/5/2010   9/18/2010   9/5/2010     Archi    Ordinary  58.65586    0
3  EO2      C    TO   9/21/2000  9/10/2010  9/18/2010   9/10/2010    Archi    Ordinary  58.65586    0
4  EO2      C    TO   9/21/2000  9/24/2010  9/18/2010   9/24/2010    Archi    Ordinary  58.65586    0
```

I have written below query:

```
select * from T a
join T b on a.ID = b.ID
where a.[Number] = b.[Number] and a.ID >1
```

Also, I tied this:

```
SELECT * FROM T a WHERE a.Id IN (SELECT b.Id FROM T b)
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM T a
```

The problem is I'm not able to find a way, where each row can be compared with each other with above date condition.I should get the result like below as duplicate:

```
Number  Code Type   date1     Date2       date3        Date4     status   shortname     CP      deferred
EO2     C    TO   9/20/2000  9/1/2010   9/18/2010   9/1/2010     Archi    Ordinary  58.65586    0
EO2     C    TO   9/20/2000  9/5/2010   9/18/2010   9/5/2010     Archi    Ordinary  58.65586    0
EO2     C    TO   9/21/2000  9/10/2010  9/18/2010   9/10/2010    Archi    Ordinary  58.65586    0
```

Please help.Thanks.

Comment: The third row in your example has a different `date1`, so how can it still be duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this. Thanks for help.

```
select t1.Number,t1.Code,t1.Type,t1.date1,t1.Date2,t1.date3,t1.Date4,t1.stats,t1.shortn‌​ame,t1.CP, t1.deferred 
from T t1 join T t2 on 1=1 and t2.Number = t1.Number and t2.Code = t1.Code and t2.Type = t1.Type and t2.deferred = t1.eferred and t2.CP = t1.CP and t2.status = t1.status and abs(datediff(day,t1.Date2,t2.Date2)) <=10 and abs(datediff(day,t1.date3,t2.date3)) <=10 and abs(datediff(day,t1.Date4,t2.Date4)) <=10 group by t1.Number, t1.Code,t1.Type , t1.date1, t1.Date2,t1.date3,t1.Date4 ,t1.status,t1.shortname,t1.CP, t1.deferred having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `join` to search for other identical rows.  A `join` tries to match all rows from the right hand table based on the `on` condition.  For example:

```
select  *
from    YourTable t1
join    YourTable t2
on      t1.ID < t2.ID -- Must be different rows
                      -- Smaller than presents the duplicates once
                      -- Otherwise you'd get both 1,3 and 3,1
        and abs(datediff(day, t1.date2, t2.date2)) <= 10
        and abs(datediff(day, t1.date4, t2.date4)) <= 10
        and t1.Number = t2.Number
        and t1.Code = t2.Code
        and -- So on for every column that should be equal
```

To ignore a column, omit it from the `on` condition.

Comment: If I use this condition (t1.ID < t2.ID) ; I'm not getting any records. However, if I remove this condition, getting records but wrong results. I'm bit confused.Can I use "group by" and count(*) > 1 with this "ABS"? Its OK, if I'll not get ID in my output. Any example scheme, on which you have tried?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Setting up an example schema at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) would help to clarify your issue

Comment: Link not opening.I mean is: select t1.Number,t1.Code,t1.Type,t1.date1,t1.Date2,t1.date3,t1.Date4,t1.stats,t1.shortname,t1.CP, t1.deferred
from T t1
join T t2 on 1=1 and 
t2.Number = t1.Number
and t2.Code = t1.Code
and t2.Type = t1.Type
and t2.deferred = t1.eferred
and t2.CP = t1.CP
and t2.status = t1.status
and abs(datediff(day,t1.Date2,t2.Date2)) <=10
and abs(datediff(day,t1.date3,t2.date3)) <=10
and abs(datediff(day,t1.Date4,t2.Date4)) <=10
group by t1.Number, t1.Code,t1.Type
, t1.date1, t1.Date2,t1.date3,t1.Date4
,t1.status,t1.shortname,t1.CP, t1.deferred
having count(*) > 1,Will this work?