# Matching people without national ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

I'm trying to match people in a table with initial, last name, and birth date

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702346/compare-each-records-of-same-table-in-sql-server-and-return-duplicates/30702457#30702457) which helps reduce the number of matches to IDs older than the current one (so 3 matches to 1 but 1 does not match to 3)

But im having the problem with 1,2 and 3 being matches, the result has
3-2
3-1
2-1

how can i make it so 3 only matches to 1?

This is the code i'm using

```
select  *
from    
    YourTable t1
    join    YourTable t2 on t1.ID < t2.ID 
    and t1.initial= t2.initial
    and t1.lastname= t2.lastname
    and t1.birth= t2.birth
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results are likely going to be really helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be like this?

```
 select  t2.id, min(t1.id)
from    
    YourTable t1
    join    YourTable t2 on t1.ID < t2.ID 
    and t1.initial= t2.initial
    and t1.lastname= t2.lastname
    and t1.birth= t2.birth
group by t2.id
```