# Matching people without national ID V2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to match people in a table with initial, last name, and birth date

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702346/compare-each-records-of-same-table-in-sql-server-and-return-duplicates/30702457#30702457) which helps reduce the number of matches to IDs older than the current one (so 3 matches to 1 but 1 does not match to 3)

Im having the problem with 1,2 and 3 being matches, the result has

```
3-2  
3-1  
2-1
```

how can i make it so 3 only matches to 1?

This is the code i'm using

```
select  t1.id, t1.date, t1.initial, t1.lastname, t1.birth, min (t2.id)
from    
    YourTable t1
    join    YourTable t2 on t1.date< t2.date --date when the record was created
    and t1.initial= t2.initial
    and t1.lastname= t2.lastname
    and t1.birth= t2.birth
    Group by t1.id, t1.date, t1.initial, t1.lastname, t1.birth
```

I also got a response in my previous quesiton [my previous quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651097/matching-people-without-national-id) but after some trial and error it turns out the ID used is not numerical but a hash, so MIN() doesnt always work.
So a valid output from the query would be
`select  t1.id, t1.date, t1.initial, t1.lastname, t1.birth, min (t2.date)`
but then i dont know the t2.id

what would be an efficient way to get the t2.id?

SAMPLE DATA:

```
+-------+------------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| T1.ID |  T1.Date   | T2.ID |  T2.Date   | T1.Birth  | T1.initial | T1.lastname | T1.gender |
+-------+------------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 0x547 | 4/7/2018   | 0xB29 | 11/2/2013  | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x547 | 4/7/2018   | 0x75D | 11/26/2013 | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x75D | 11/26/2013 | 0xB29 | 11/2/2013  | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0xD50 | 5/18/2018  | 0xB29 | 11/2/2013  | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0xD50 | 5/18/2018  | 0x75D | 11/26/2013 | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0xD50 | 5/18/2018  | 0x547 | 4/7/2018   | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x817 | 5/20/2018  | 0xB29 | 11/2/2013  | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x817 | 5/20/2018  | 0x75D | 11/26/2013 | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x817 | 5/20/2018  | 0x547 | 4/7/2018   | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x817 | 5/20/2018  | 0xD50 | 5/18/2018  | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x013 | 9/28/2018  | 0xB29 | 11/2/2013  | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x013 | 9/28/2018  | 0x75D | 11/26/2013 | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x013 | 9/28/2018  | 0x547 | 4/7/2018   | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x013 | 9/28/2018  | 0x817 | 5/20/2018  | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
| 0x013 | 9/28/2018  | 0xD50 | 5/18/2018  | 8/10/1956 | A          | B           |         1 |
+-------+------------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *for this question*.  References to other questions can be helpful for supplementary information, but each question should have its own complete information.

Comment: thanks EzLo for the edit fix!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using row_number () over partition using the dates and getting a rank. Putting this query into a with and filtering in another query for lines with rank = 1